# Ruby on Rails - using helpers in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, helper

I'm probably missing some things. 
Say for example I have a helper function in app/helpers/foo_controller.rb and the code is as follows:

```
def sample_helper(count)
    #implementaton...
end
```

and I want to use this helper in a webpage generated by rails and the code is as follows:

```
    <%= sample_helper(user.id) %>
```

and if I try to run the webpage it will throw me an error saying that the method is not defined.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it will probably be better for you to look railscasts and himself to find a solution [Custom Helper Modules](http://railscasts.com/episodes/64-custom-helper-modules)

Answer (score 4):

You don't quite have the naming conventions right.

Name your helper file `app/helpers/foo_helper.rb` and in it you should have this:

```
module FooHelper
  def sample_helper(count)
    "#{count} items" # or whatever
  end
end
```

And now, from any view rendered by `FooController` you should be able to use the `sample_helper` method.

---

Also, you should know that if you use the rails generators this structure is setup for you.  All you need to do is add methods to the files that get generated.  That way you don't need to guess the naming conventions.

For example, this command will make a controller file, controller test files, a helper file, and and an index view file, all ready for you to customize.

```
rails g controller foo index
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your helper should be in a file called app/helpers/**foo_helper.rb** that contains a a module of the same name as the helper (camelized) Like:

```
module FooHelper 
  def sample_helper(cont)
    # implementation
  end
end
```

That's the way Rail auto loads helpers.